# How to check if parallel portlet rendering is working or not

Tags: portlet, websphere-6.1, websphere-portal

I have enabled parallel portlet rendering in Webspere portal server 6.1.5. by following the below steps

```
legacy.useParallelRendering.html = true
std.useParallelRendering.html = true
```

And at individual portlet level as well.

Could somebody please suggest how can I check if this is working at runtime or not.

Regrads, 
Snehan Solomon

Answer (score 0):

Create a portlet that prints out a log at its start and at its end. Do a `Thred.sleep` in between. Add it several times to your portlet page and open that page. Check if the logs overlap or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify this by checking the logs. You will see text like `WorkManager` in the log file.